# SMO v11 (SQL Server 2012) not scripting key definitions, indexes, and constraints

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, powershell, smo

I have a `.ps1` PowerShell script that runs on a Central Management Server. The script goes out to all databases in our environment, and scripts out all of of objects. For tables scripts, the output files have always included the table definition along with constraints, primary keys, and indexes.

We recently upgraded our CMS to Powershell 3.0 and SQL Server 2012 and now our output scripts have table definition only. The indexes, constraints, and key definitions are no longer part of the script. Does anyone know what has changed with SMO in this SQL Server 2012 release and how I can resolve my issue.

My code is below.

```
# LoopInstances

$InstanceListFile = "C:\temp\serverlist.txt"
$CurrentDay = Get-Date -Format dd
$InstanceList = Get-Content $InstanceListFile

foreach ($InstanceName in $InstanceList)
{
    if (($InstanceName -ne 'Server1') -and ($InstanceName -ne 'Server2'))
    {
    # Configuration
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO") | Out-Null
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.SMOExtended')  | out-null
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication") | Out-Null
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.RMO") | Out-Null

    $MyScripter = New-Object "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.Scripter"

    $InstanceObject = New-Object "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.Server" "$InstanceName"

    $RepInstanceObject = New-Object "Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.ReplicationServer" "$InstanceName"

    # The SetDefaultInitFields method tells the SMO API to add the IsSystemObject property to the default list for this session

    $InstanceObject.SetDefaultInitFields("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.ExtendedStoredProcedure", "IsSystemObject")
    $InstanceObject.SetDefaultInitFields("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.StoredProcedure", "IsSystemObject")
    $InstanceObject.SetDefaultInitFields("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.Table", "IsSystemObject")
    $InstanceObject.SetDefaultInitFields("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.View", "IsSystemObject")
    $InstanceObject.SetDefaultInitFields("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.UserDefinedFunction", "IsSystemObject")
    $MyScripter.Server = $InstanceObject
    $ScripterOptions = $MyScripter.Options

    # SetScriptOptions

    $ScripterOptions.ToFileOnly = $True
    $ScripterOptions.AppendToFile = $True
    $ScripterOptions.ContinueScriptingOnError = $True
    $ScripterOptions.LoginSid = $True
    $ScripterOptions.AgentAlertJob = $True
    $ScripterOptions.AgentNotify = $True
    $ScripterOptions.Bindings = $True
    $ScripterOptions.DriAll = $True
    $ScripterOptions.Indexes = $True
    $ScripterOptions.Permissions = $True
    $ScripterOptions.SchemaQualify = $True
    $ScripterOptions.Triggers = $True
    $ScripterOptions.IncludeIfNotExists = $True
    $ScripterOptions.ExtendedProperties = $True

    # SetSchemaPath


    $SchemaPath = "C:\Temp\" + $CurrentDay + "\" + $InstanceName
    if ((Test-Path $SchemaPath) -ne $True) {mkdir $SchemaPath | Out-Null} 

    # DisplayInstance

    Write-Host "------------------------------------------------------------"
    Write-Host $InstanceName - (Get-Date)
    Write-Host "------------------------------------------------------------"

    # CheckVersion

    if ($InstanceObject.Information.VersionString.substring(0,2) -eq 10)
    {

        $InstanceObjectList = "Audits","BackupDevices","Credentials","CryptographicProviders","Databases","EndPoints","LinkedServers","Logins","ServerAuditSpecifications","Triggers","UserDefinedMessages"
        $JobServerObjectList = "AlertCategories","Alerts","JobCategories","Jobs","OperatorCategories","Operators","ProxyAccounts","SharedSchedules","TargetServerGroups","TargetServers"
        $DatabaseObjectList = "Assemblies","AsymmetricKeys","Certificates","DatabaseAuditSpecifications","Defaults","ExtendedProperties","FullTextCatalogs","FullTextStopLists","PartitionFunctions","PartitionSchemes","PlanGuides","Roles","Rules","Schemas","Synonyms","Triggers","UserDefinedAggregates","UserDefinedDataTypes","UserDefinedTableTypes","UserDefinedTypes","Users","XmlSchemaCollections"
    }

    if ($InstanceObject.Information.VersionString.substring(0,1) -eq 9)
    {
        $InstanceObjectList = "BackupDevices","Credentials","Databases","EndPoints","LinkedServers","Logins","Triggers","UserDefinedMessages"
        $JobServerObjectList = "AlertCategories","Alerts","JobCategories","Jobs","OperatorCategories","Operators","ProxyAccounts","SharedSchedules","TargetServerGroups","TargetServers"
        $DatabaseObjectList = "Assemblies","AsymmetricKeys","Certificates","Defaults","ExtendedProperties","FullTextCatalogs","PartitionFunctions","PartitionSchemes","Roles","Rules","Schemas","Synonyms","Triggers","UserDefinedAggregates","UserDefinedDataTypes","UserDefinedTypes","Users","XmlSchemaCollections"
    }

    if ($InstanceObject.Information.VersionString.substring(0,1) -eq 8)
    {
        $InstanceObjectList = "BackupDevices","Databases","LinkedServers","Logins","UserDefinedMessages"
        $JobServerObjectList = "AlertCategories","Alerts","JobCategories","Jobs","OperatorCategories","Operators","TargetServerGroups","TargetServers"
        $DatabaseObjectList = "Defaults","ExtendedProperties","FullTextCatalogs","Roles","Rules","UserDefinedDataTypes","Users"
    }

    # ScriptInstance

    Write-Host Instance
    foreach($Object in $InstanceObjectList)
    {
        Write-Host "    " $Object


        $ScripterOptions.FileName=$SchemaPath + "\Instance_" + $Object + ".sql"


        if ((Test-Path $ScripterOptions.FileName) -eq $True)
        {
            del $ScripterOptions.FileName
        }


        $InstanceObjectCombined = $InstanceObject.$Object
        $MyScripter.Script([Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject[]]$InstanceObjectCombined)


        if ($? -eq $False)
        {
            Write-Host "FAILED - SCRIPT ABORTED"
        }
    }

        # ScriptJobServer

    if ($InstanceObject.Information.Edition -ne 'Express Edition')
    {
        Write-Host JobServer
        foreach($Object in $JobServerObjectList)
        {
            Write-Host "    " $Object
            $ScripterOptions.FileName=$SchemaPath + "\JobServer_" + $Object + ".sql"
            if ((Test-Path $ScripterOptions.FileName) -eq $True)
            {
                del $ScripterOptions.FileName
            }
            $InstanceObjectJobServer = $InstanceObject.JobServer.$Object
            $MyScripter.Script([Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject[]]$InstanceObjectJobServer)
            if ($? -eq $False)
            {
                Write-Host "FAILED - SCRIPT ABORTED"
#               exit 1
            }
        }
    }


        # ScriptDatabases

    $DatabaseFilter = $InstanceObject.Databases | where {$_.Name -ne "distribution"} | where {$_.Name -ne "master"} | where {$_.Name -ne "msdb"} | where {$_.Name -ne "tempdb"}
    foreach($Database in $DatabaseFilter)
    {
        Write-Host $Database
        foreach($Object in $DatabaseObjectList)
        {
            Write-Host "    " $Object
            $ScripterOptions.FileName=$SchemaPath + "\Database_" + $Database.name + "_" + $Object + ".sql"
            if ((Test-Path $ScripterOptions.FileName) -eq $True)
            {
                del $ScripterOptions.FileName
            }
            $ScripterOptions.Permissions = $True
            $InstanceObjectDatabases = $InstanceObject.Databases[$Database.name].$Object
            $MyScripter.Script([Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject[]]$InstanceObjectDatabases)
            if ($? -eq $False)
            {
                Write-Host "FAILED - SCRIPT ABORTED"
#               exit 1
            }
        }

        foreach($Object in "ExtendedStoredProcedures","StoredProcedures","Tables","Views","UserDefinedFunctions")
        {
            Write-Host "    " $Object
            $ScripterOptions.FileName=$SchemaPath + "\Database_" + $Database.name + "_" + $Object + ".sql"
            if ((Test-Path $ScripterOptions.FileName) -eq $True)
            {
                del $ScripterOptions.FileName
            }
            $ObjectFilter = $InstanceObject.Databases[$Database.name].$Object | where {$_.IsSystemObject -eq $False}
            if ($ObjectFilter)
            {
                $ScripterOptions.Permissions = $True
                $MyScripter.Script([Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject[]]$ObjectFilter)
                if ($? -eq $False)
                {
                    Write-Host "FAILED - SCRIPT ABORTED"
#                   exit 1
                }
            }
        }
    }

    # ScriptReplication - Added after all SMO scripting to avoid bug detected in losing the database context

    $RepScriptOptions = [Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.scriptoptions]::Creation `
    -bor  [Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.scriptoptions]::IncludeArticles `
    -bor  [Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.scriptoptions]::IncludePublisherSideSubscriptions `
    -bor  [Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.scriptoptions]::IncludeSubscriberSideSubscriptions

    Write-Host Replication
    foreach($ReplicatedDatabase in $RepInstanceObject.ReplicationDatabases) 
    {
        $ScriptFileName=$SchemaPath + "\Replication_" + $ReplicatedDatabase.Name + ".sql"
        if ((Test-Path $ScriptFileName) -eq $True)
        {
            del $ScriptFileName
        }
            foreach($Publication in $ReplicatedDatabase.TransPublications) 
            {
            Write-Host "    " $Publication.Name
                $Publication.Script($RepScriptOptions) >> $ScriptFileName
            if ($? -eq $False)
            {
                Write-Host "FAILED - SCRIPT ABORTED"
#               exit 1
            }
            }
            foreach($Publication in $ReplicatedDatabase.MergePublications) 
            {
            Write-Host "    " $Publication.Name
                $Publication.Script($RepScriptOptions) >> $ScriptFileName
            if ($? -eq $False)
            {
                Write-Host "FAILED - SCRIPT ABORTED"
#               exit 1
            }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a version check SQL 2012? You're bypassing an important step in your script. In other words:

    if ($InstanceObject.Information.VersionString.substring(0,2) -eq 11)

Comment: Non of the environments that we are scripting from is 2012 yet. They are all 2008 or 2008R2. The management server, which this scripts runs from, is the only one that is 2012 as of yet.

Comment: But yes, you are correct, and that line of code will need to be added as we upgrade our other servers in the coming months...

Comment: I see others reporting the same behavior and the consensus seems to be that it is an incompatibility between the SMO versions. Not sure that is correct. Maybe open a Connect item.

Comment: I added the version check for 11 and ran it against a SQL 2012 instance and it still doesn't work. Not convinced it is a version incompatibility.

Comment: I'm assuming you meant you are "now" convinced its a version incompatibility.

Comment: Posted bug on Connect.  http://bit.ly/U7CWd2

Answer (score 4):

I'm unable to reproduce the issue you describe. Here's simplified script I used to test from 2012 and 2008 R2 to a 2008 R2 server. Comment/Uncomment the add-type section as needed. One thought is that using deprecated LoadWithPartialName could be causing issues if you have both 2008 and 2012 assemblies on same machine.

```
#SQL 2008 R2
#add-type -AssemblyName "Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"
#add-type -AssemblyName "Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"
#add-type -AssemblyName "Microsoft.SqlServer.SMOExtended, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"

#SQL 2012
add-type -AssemblyName "Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"
add-type -AssemblyName "Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"
add-type -AssemblyName "Microsoft.SqlServer.SMOExtended, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"

$InstanceName = "myservername"

$query = @"
CREATE TABLE dbo.authors(
    au_id int NOT NULL,
    au_lname varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    au_fname varchar(20) NOT NULL

 CONSTRAINT UPKCL_auidind PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    au_id ASC
)
) 
"@

$InstanceObject = New-Object "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.Server" "$InstanceName"

$db = $InstanceObject.Databases['tempdb']
$db.ExecuteNonQuery($query)

$MyScripter = New-Object "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.Scripter"

$MyScripter.Server = $InstanceObject

$MyScripter.Options.DriAll = $true
#$MyScripter.Options.DriPrimaryKey = $false
#$MyScripter.Options.DriClustered = $false

$MyScripter.Script($InstanceObject.Databases['tempdb'].Tables['authors'])
```

Comment: Thanks! You answer helped me. In my case there were no constraints scripted JUST because I didn't explicitly set assemblies (I was using PartialName).